# How do I indicate my Windows Service is not pausable?

Tags: windows-services

https://serverfault.com/questions/70028/pausing-a-not-pausable-service-pausing-a-not-pausable-service-from-the-command talks about pausing a NOT_PAUSABLE service. How do I indicate my service is not pausable to begin with? I want my service to only support the start/stop operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your service, you filled out [a `SERVICE_STATUS` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685996%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). One of the fields in the structure is called `dwControlsAccepted`. One of the options for `dwControlsAccepted` is `SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE`. If you don't say you support pause/continue, then it will be reported by SCM as not supporting pause/continue.

Answer (score 1):

Checking Windows Service :

e.g Checking DNS Client

```
Service keyname      : DNScache
Service Displayname  : DNS Client
```

USING : ***SC QUERY***

RUN CMD (Command Prompt) > Type:

```
SC QUERY DNSCACHE
```

Result:

```
SERVICE_NAME: DNSCACHE
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

State Code:

- 4 : Running. Possibility to Stop, or pause depend from the service itself
- 7 : Paused. Possibility to Stop, or pause depend from the service itself. of course Continuable
- 1 : Stopped. Already Stopped Not Stoppable or Pausable ;)

CODE

```
SC GETKEYNAME **YOUR SERVICE**
SC GETDISPLAYNAME **YOUR SERVICE**   
SC                                   >> Showing Other Command Available
```

[ Funny thing: i can't get Key Name (SC GETKEYNAME) from DNS Client but showing Display Name (SC GETDISPLAYNAME) from DNSCACHE ]

Read carefully the question again from that link, been answered i think :)

Windows XP Services: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-services.html

Answer (score 0):

I came to this post trying to make my service pausable. I was able to set this via the CanPauseAndContinue property in the constructor of my service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canpauseandcontinue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1